# How to highlight intersection between objects in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality, intersection

I'm new to Unity and I'm developing an augmented reality app.

My situation is as follows: I have two objects in the scene, a neighborhood model and a cube. The mockup will be the object I am going to enlarge and the cube will be like the acrylic box where the mockup is. The cube represents the viewing area and will be transparent. The model has an animation in which it moves and scales and the cube remains fixed.

I need something to assign to the cube so that when expanding the model, the parts that stick out of the cube will have 50% colorless transparency (all gray) and the part of the model that is inside the cube (in intersection) remains solid and with the colors and textures.

The idea is to present the mockup on an initial scale that is inside the cube (acrylic box) then the model's animation will zoom in on the mockup at certain points, the whole mockup will be much larger than the cube. the outside of the cube is transparent and colorless, and the inside remains coloured  to make it more prominent.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hey JONATAS, what did you try so far to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Liastre

I found a tutorial that does exactly what I need:

http://halisavakis.com/my-take-on-shaders-spherical-mask-dissolve/

However, the shader or mask is spherical. I need it to be rectangular and the script settings in the inspector allow me to adjust the length, height and width.

To simulate my "acrylic box" around the mockup that will "cut" the mockup when it is enlarged.

Like the image below but the cut will be rectangular and not circular.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI3zl.png)